# ASP.NET Jquery DateTimePicker Server Side Function Not Getting Called

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datetime, datetimepicker

I am trying to make it so when I click on an input a jquery datetimepicker appears and allows the user to input the correct date and time which then will be put into the input. My Method was working but now I changed some of the front end code and am getting the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: saveCompletionTime_Click is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<tr>
                <td>Propsed End Date/Time: </td>
                <td><input type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormProposedEndDatePO" OnClick="saveCompletionTime_Click"/></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="eventFormProposedEndDatePO" 
                        ErrorMessage="*Proposed end date/time is required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

My Javascript is as follows:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id$=eventFormCompletionTime]").datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD MMM YYYY hh:mm A',
            ampm: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my Code Behind File is as follows:

```
protected void saveCompletionTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (typeHolder.Value == "SD")
        {
            DateTime dob = DateTime.Parse(Request.Form[eventFormStartTimeSD.UniqueID]);
        }
        else if (typeHolder.Value == "PO")
        {
            DateTime dob = DateTime.Parse(Request.Form[eventFormProposedStartDatePO.UniqueID]);
        }

    }
```

The saveCompletionTime_Click() is never being called in the code behind file but the click on the input is being registered.

Comment: Maybe clarify that you are using bootstrap Library. Next time include a bootstrap tag :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your current "OnClick" event can only call client-side code. Instead, you should try an ASP control.

For example:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSaveTime" runat="server" OnClick="saveCompletionTime_Click" Text="Save Time"     />
```

Comment: Your answer works but makes the element a button and I want it to be an input. You can see how I solved it above thanks for the help though!

Comment: I can see how you got it to work.
you can add to your current input runat="server".

Answer (score 0):

I just had to change the javascript call from:

```
$("[id$=eventFormCompletionTime]")
```

to

```
$("[id$=eventFormProposedEndDatePO]")
```

There must be something that makes the client call work even though it is weird since the input is not an asp element so it cant make server calls directly.